# ElasticSearch - auditable solution with "not modificable" documents?

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-s3, snapshot

As started here:
https://discuss.elastic.co/t/write-only-cluster-index-auditing-porpouse/49494

I'm looking for a way to guarantee, that **documents written to the ES cluster can not be changed** (or at least there is backup with original content) - audit requirements.

For the moment I can secure a snapshot, so hard that even I can not modify/delete it. But what about the time from last snapshot until now?

Do You know a way of securing ES snapshot, so that it would be 'write-only' cluster :) ?

---

Possible solution?:
Ban the URI: XDELETE, */_update, but what about 'whole document update' where _version number changes?

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve this would be to use the official [Shield](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/shield/current/index.html) product and define [read-only privileges](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/shield/current/shield-privileges.html#privileges-list-indices) on the indices you want to freeze. Below, the role `readonly` would only have read access to all indices, while `full` has full access:

```
readonly:
  indices:
    - names: '*'
      privileges:
        - read
writer:
  indices:
    - names: '*'
      privileges:
        - read
        - write
```

UPDATE: The `write` privilege allows the user to create, update and delete documents. There's a finer grained privilege called [`create`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/shield/current/shield-privileges.html#privileges-list-indices), which only allows to create/index new documents, but neither update nor delete them.

Another way, would be to use the excellent [read-only REST plugin](https://github.com/sscarduzio/elasticsearch-readonlyrest-plugin) by [@sscarduzio](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1094616/sscarduzio), with the following configuration:

```
readonly:
    enable: true
    response_if_req_forbidden: Sorry, your request is forbidden.
    access_control_rules:

    - name: Read-only audit indices
      type: allow
      actions: [cluster:*, indices:data/read/*]
      indices: ["*"]

writer:
    enable: true
    response_if_req_forbidden: Sorry, your request is forbidden.
    access_control_rules:

    - name: Indexer process
      type: allow
      actions: [cluster:*, indices:data/write/*]
      indices: ["*"]
```

The main advantage of this approach is that you can still define another role (e.g. `writer`) who will be able to contribute/index new documents, while still allowing other roles (e.g. `readonly`) to be read-only.

Comment: any way to disable 'document update (in-place) option?'

Comment: In Shield, you have different privileges, namely the [`create` one](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/shield/current/shield-privileges.html#privileges-list-indices) which only gives the ability to create documents, but neither to update them nor to delete them. That's probably what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

From [the documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/misc-cluster.html#cluster-read-only):

> **cluster.blocks.read_only**
>   Make the whole cluster read only (indices do not accept write operations), metadata is not allowed to be modified (create or delete indices).

And for

> Don’t rely on this setting to prevent changes to your cluster. Any user with access to the cluster-update-settings API can make the cluster read-write again.

You can ban only any calls to `PUT localhost:9200/_cluster/settings`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I can not make the index read only - the data is uploaded all the time.
I'd like to disable 'document update' feature.